# Form validation on keydown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following semantic structure for a form

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="signUp" id="signUp" novalidate>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Sign Up</legend>
        <div class="form-group inputEmail">
            <label for="inputUsername" class="col-lg-2 control-label" >Username</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type='email' class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Your Email" maxlength="56" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group inputPassword">
            <label for="inputPassword" class="col-lg-2 control-label" >Password</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type='password' class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Your Password" minlength="6" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

My objective is to perform validation on the specific input elements in the form on keydown. I have the following snippet of jQuery code that does that

```
$('#signUp').keydown(function(){
    signUp.usernameValid(); //performs validation
    signUp.passwordValidity(); //performs validation
});
```

I am trying to follow the event delegation technique. But the issue that i have run into and currently trying to figure out, is, how to focus on  specific elements when keydown event is fired on the form element?

Based on the above code, once the keydown event is fired all the validations will be fired for the input elements instead of the specific one

Comment: Why would you be doing this at the Form level? It makes much more sense to validate each input separately, possibly on `blur`, or perhaps when the Form is submitted. It sounds like you're trying to provide real-time validation, so watching each individual input makes more sense (to me).

Comment: Hi Mark, yes i am trying to achieve real time validation, the case is what if i have more than 2 input elements. Is the only option i have is to watch each input element individually?

Comment: The problem with doing it at the Form level is that you're not sure where the user is in their process of filling out the Form. Did they only enter something in the first input, but not the next 3? If they are still filling out the inputs, and you're continuously evaluating the entire Form, you're not giving the user a chance to finish what they are doing. I hope that makes sense, but you could have a business case which I don't know about.

Comment: No business case, just curiosity. Trying to see if i could maintain the main event on the parent element instead of every single element to perform the validation

Comment: Well, you can always monitor the state of each input at the parent level, certainly. But I'm not sure what that will buy you in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#inputEmail').keydown(function (e) {
   if (e.ctrlKey || e.altKey) {
    //e.preventDefault();
    $("#errg").html("Allow only alphabets").show().fadeOut("slow");
               return false;
   } else {
    var key = e.keyCode;
    if (!((key == 8) ||(key == 9) || (key == 32) || (key == 46) || (key >= 35 && key <= 40) || (key >= 65 && key <= 90))) {
     $("#errg").html("Allow only alphabets").show().fadeOut("slow");
                 return false;
    }
   }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#signUp input').on('keydown', function(){
  //this will give you the specific element
  console.log($(this));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="form-horizontal" name="signUp" id="signUp" novalidate>
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>Sign Up</legend>
                            <div class="form-group inputEmail">
                                <label for="inputUsername" class="col-lg-2 control-label" >Username</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <input type='email' class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Your Email" maxlength="56" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group inputPassword">
                                <label for="inputPassword" class="col-lg-2 control-label" >Password</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <input type='password' class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Your Password" minlength="6" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
```